# Partition by a seq of integers

Tags: clojure

What would be a more idiomatic way to partition a seq based on a seq of integers instead of just one integer?

Here's my implementation:

```
(defn partition-by-seq
  "Return a lazy sequence of lists with a variable number of items each
  determined by the n in ncoll.  Extra values in coll are dropped."
  [ncoll coll]
  (let [partition-coll (mapcat #(repeat % %) ncoll)]
    (->> coll
         (map vector partition-coll)
         (partition-by first)
         (map (partial map last)))))
```

Then `(partition-by-seq [2 3 6] (range))` yields `((0 1) (2 3 4) (5 6 7 8 9 10))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variation on Ankur's answer, with a minor addition of laziness and `when-let` instead of an explicit test for `empty?`.

```
 (defn partition-by-seq [parts coll]
    (lazy-seq
      (when-let [s (seq parts)]
        (cons
          (take (first s) coll)
          (partition-by-seq (rest s) (nthrest coll (first s)))))))
```

Comment: I like the use of `when-let` here since (cons x nil) is just (x), and find that much cleaner than the "if" version.  Why use `nthrest` instead of `drop`?  It seems like the inner part could be `(when-let [n (first parts)] (cons (take n coll) (partition-by-seq (rest parts) (drop n coll))))`

Comment: @ToBeReplaced `nthrest` is just `drop` that drops eagerly, which I thought was appropriate in this context. On second thought, I'm not sure if it matters at all. Indeed, the `first` can be moved inside the `when-let`.

Answer (score 4):

Your implementation looks fine, but there could be a more simple solution which uses simple recursion wrapped in `lazy-seq`(and turns out to be more efficient) than using map and existing partition-by as in your case.

```
(defn partition-by-seq [ncoll coll]
  (if (empty? ncoll)
    '()
    (let [n (first ncoll)]
      (cons (take n coll)
            (lazy-seq (partition-by-seq (rest ncoll) (drop n coll)))))))
```

Comment: This could be made even lazier by taking `lazy-seq` outside `cons`, so that even the first `(take n coll)` is not eagerly evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

```
(first (reduce (fn [[r l] n]
                 [(conj r (take n l)) (drop n l)])
               [[] (range)]
               [2 3 6]))

=> [(0 1) (2 3 4) (5 6 7 8 9 10)]
```